# Set cookies in Flex URLRequest

Tags: apache-flex, cookies, file-upload

I'm trying to set a cookie in a Flex, but it doesn't seem to work.  Am I doing something wrong?  Is this possible?  It seems like this should be simple.

```
var fileRef:FileReference;
// fileRef is configured

var cookieString:String = "my cookies";
var cookieHeader:URLRequestHeader= new URLRequestHeader("Cookie", cookieString);

var url:String = 'my url'; 
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url); 
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; 
request.requestHeaders.push(cookieHeader);
fileRef.upload(request);
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is, I cannot make a authenticated web service request through OpenAm without using cookies, and I cannot figure out how to place the cookies in the Flex file upload request (well actually this works in IE, but is broken in Firefox and Chrome - [I read that this is because IE uploads the file in the same browser thread while some other browsers spawn a new thread, and the cookie information does not get passed along](http://jimmyflex.blogspot.com/2010/05/fixing-file-upload-session-issue-with.html)).

Comment: Why do you need cookies to make a secure web request?

Comment: We use OpenAM as our authentication and authorization framework.  It use cookies to authorize authenticated users to access web services.  It does not have an option to run "cookieless", hence I cannot access the services without setting the cookies in the request.  Maybe "secure" was not the best term to use, since it does not relate strictly to https - although we're using that as well (if it matters).  I edited the question to help clear up the confusion.

Comment: I don't understand why you would have to set these cookies manually in the request header.  The browser already have the cookies when set and include them automatically to all server requests, including those made by the Flash Player.  Is your SWF on the same domain as the web service?

Comment: This is why the cookies don't get passed along and they need to get set manually - http://jimmyflex.blogspot.com/2010/05/fixing-file-upload-session-issue-with.html.  I can't use the solution offered here because OpenAM does not use JSESSIONID and doesn't not support cookieless behavior.  Yes - the SWF and web services are on the same domain.  This works in IE, but is broken in FF & Chrome (and possibly others).

Comment: Now I understand the problem.  Unfortunately I don't have a solution.