# Will OpenAM work if cookies are disabled?

Tags: cookies, openam

Will OpenAM work if cookies are disabled?

I have a Flex application and on some browsers (Chrome, Firefox), [when a file upload is attempted, the flash player will not pass the OpenAM cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841642/set-cookies-in-flex-urlrequest).  I need to find another way to do this.  Is there any way to use OpenAM when cookies are disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by default, but you may be able to modify the OpenAM source code to do so.

From [the OpenAM mailing list](https://lists.forgerock.org/mailman/listinfo/openam):

> if you check out the source code of
>   SSOProviderImpl#createSSOToken(HttpServletRequest) it looks like there
>   are methods trying to get the session id from the request
>   parametermap, so IMHO you should be able to post the
>   cookiename=cookievalue along with your file, or put the session ID on
>   the querystring (but that will be logged in the container access
>   logs...)